# Efficient way to get an object from collection by value of one of its fields

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.9

The following function is given one of the following possible inputs:

- ID (numeric string)
- email (string ending with @domain.tld)
- name (any other alphanumeric string consisting)

If anything other than ID is given, it attempts to retrieve user ID by comparing a given attribute to the respective field of each user from a list of User objects, all of which have ID fields.
E.g., if an email is given, it should find a User from a list of Users that has the given email in its email field, then return value from this user's ID field.
In Django that would look like that `User.objects.filter(email=input_string).first()`

In my code, the following line is doing that:
`user := next((user for user in users if user.email == input_string)`
It looks suboptimal and ugly, but I'm struggling to find a neater solution.
Would appreciate any advice on that.

```python
def validate_user_id(input_string, users):
    if input_string.isdigit():
        return {'type': 'user', 'id': input_string}
    elif input_string.endswith(MAIL_DOMAIN):
        if user := next((user for user in users if user.email == input_string), None):
            return {'type': 'user', 'id': user.id}
        return None
    elif (input_string.isalnum() or
          ''.join(input_string.split('.')).isalnum()):
        if user := next((user for user in users if user.nickname == input_string), None):
            return {'type': 'user', 'id': user.id}
        return None
    raise ValueError(
        MEMBER_FORMAT_INVALID.format(identifier=input_string))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code more DRY and optimized use the following approach:

- check the input string format to recognize the user's target attribute
- instead of whole `user` object yield `user.id` from generator expression

---

```
def validate_user_id(input_str, users):
    if input_str.isdigit():  # base case
        return {'type': 'user', 'id': input_str}

    if input_str.endswith(MAIL_DOMAIN):
        attr = 'email'
    elif (input_str.isalnum() or
          ''.join(input_str.split('.')).isalnum()):
        attr = 'nickname'
    else:
        raise ValueError(MEMBER_FORMAT_INVALID.format(identifier=input_str))

    user_id = next((user.id for user in users
                    if getattr(user, attr) == input_str), None)
    if user_id:
        return {'type': 'user', 'id': user_id}
    return None
```

Comment: That's nice, thank you! Apart from drying the code, is the construct like next((generator expression)) to find the first match okay? Could it be further improved if we know, that there can only be a single match, since the fields are unique (in all cases)?

Comment: @GavinGreenhorn, "*Could it be further improved*" - it can be: in case if `User` represents an object model in some ORM system like `sqlalchemy` (where it's easy to filter as `session.query(User).filter_by(name = 'some name')`) or a document collection from nosql DB. Otherwise, if it's just a list of objects (of class `User`) - it would inevitably imply looping over objects to find the target, and there could be syntax-sugar alternatives (with `filter` or `operator.attrgetter`) - but those essentially same and involve looping with check for `None` at the end

Comment: I see! Thanks for making it clear. I didn't implement ORM because it's just a one-purpose script and User is the only model, but at least I am now at ease that the way it's designed this part couldn't be implemented better. Thank you!